# Convert GSM 7bit packed to text using Cygwin

Tags: text, cygwin, gsm, 7-bit

Using cygwin, I need to convert GSM 7bit to text.

For example  F832   --> xe

Comment: this is NOT a programming question. Please use Superuser for general application suggestions